# Problem with importing shapefile to PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I have problem with importing shapefile to Postgis table.

PostGIS table has:

`the_geom geometry(LineString,102067)` for geometry

Shapefile has:

```
INFO: Open of `postup_doby.shp'
using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: postup_doby (Line String)
```

ogr2ogr command is:

```
PGCLIENTENCODING=WIN1250 ogr2ogr -skipfailures --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=myname password=secure active_schema=povis user=sa" -lco DIM=2 postup_doby.shp postup_doby -append -nlt GEOMETRYCOLLECTION -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -lco FID=envi_id -nln postupove_doby PRECISION=NO
```

Error message is:

```
Insertion is likely to fail
ERROR 1: COPY statement failed.
ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiLineString) does not match column type (LineString)
CONTEXT:  COPY postupove_doby, line 1, column the_geom: "0105000020B38E01000200000001020000006C000000E4E2809372B61CC13F49396A56C030C1C24C8D97FAB41CC175C2C6B5..."
```

Problem is in shapefile, because has 10 features, which one feature has MULTILINESTRING geometry, others has LINESTRING geometry.

ogrinfo of feature with MULTILINESTRING, others has LINESTRING:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((-470428.644046349683776 -1097814.414936616783962,-470334.64799995359499 -1097731.710 ...
```

My solution is convert feature with MULTILINESTRING to LINESTRING and import to PostGIS, but I dont know, how I make it in comand line.

---

How can I resove this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I would read first http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and then run ogr2ogr with option -explodecollections.

> -**explodecollections**:
>       (starting with GDAL 1.8.0) produce one feature for each geometry in any kind of geometry collection in the source file

Something like this should work for you:

```
 ogr2ogr -explodecollections --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=myname password=secure active_schema=povis user=sa" -lco DIM=2 postup_doby.shp postup_doby -append  -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -lco FID=envi_id -nln postupove_doby PRECISION=NO
```

I believe that -skipfailures does not work with the COPY method which seems to be all-or-nothing in PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html.